# How can I skip the steps 2,3,4 in check out with opencart 1.5.1.3

Tags: checkout, opencart

When checking out in opencart 1.5.1.3, the customers have to go step 1 through 6 one by one:

1. Checkout Options
2. Account & Billing Details
3. Delivery Details
4. Delivery Method
5. Payment Method
6. Confirm Order

How can I make the payment simpler by jumping straight step 1 to step 5? I don't need step 2,3,4!

Answer (score 1):

You can't just remove all of those steps. OpenCart requires you to have that data to add to the order table, and as such you need it. It's also used in payment gateways, and is pretty integral to the whole of OC's system. So in short, you can't

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the ajax calls with your own ... and just keep the data that's needed for the checkout process in hidden fields.

I'm in the process of doing the same thing.  My customers don't need a payment method of billing details (taken care of by corp), so I'm hiding those and keeping the data in the background with hidden fields and such, then hijacking the ajax calls used when clicking "continue".